# How can I run my django project in server to run strongest?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx, server

What is the run command in django project when will run in server?

I have tried run my django project with python manage.py runserver --insecure. But I am not sure it is good idea for run project stronger.
Is it normal run project with --insecure for serve static files?

Comment: You should run your django application in [Gunicorn](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/gunicorn/) or [uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/) or any other python compatible web server.

Answer (score 0):

Serving your django app in production environment is entirely different with development. Using just "python manage.py runserver --insecure" is not a dependable solution in long term. You need to install and use nginx, gunicorn or similar apps for serving static files and handling requests. I suggest you to watch a couple of videos about "deploying django with postgresql, nginx and gunicorn"